# How to convert this recursive function to an iterative one?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am having trouble converting this method from recursive to iterative.  The problem that I am having specifically is I do not know how to convert a recursive call that is the condition of an `if` statement.

This needs to be done because the data sets that I am using are causing stack overflow exceptions.

There will have to be a stack of indices that are currently arguments being used for the recursive calls, but beyond that, I do not know what to do.

```
    public static IEnumerable<BipartiteMatch> MaximumBipartiteMatch(int m, int n, Func<int, int, bool> isMapped)
    {
        var matches = new int[n];

        for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            matches[i] = -1;
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < m; x++)
        {
            BipartiteMatch(x, n, new bool[n], matches, isMapped);
        }

        for (var index = 0; index < n; index++)
        {
            yield return new BipartiteMatch(matches[index], index);
        }
    }

    private static bool BipartiteMatch(int x, int n, bool[] seen, int[] matches, Func<int, int, bool> isMapped)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < n; y++)
        {
            if (seen[y] || !isMapped(x, y)) continue;

            seen[y] = true;

            //HERE:
            if (matches[y] >= 0 && !BipartiteMatch(matches[y], n, seen, matches, isMapped)) continue;

            matches[y] = x;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

If `matches[y] >= 0`, then we need to push the value of `matches[y]` to a stack, but I am not sure how to loop it so it simulates recursion.

My attempt (it is buggy):

```
internal static class MaximumMatchingAlgorithm
{
    internal static IEnumerable<BipartiteMatch> Solve(int m, int n, Func<int, int, bool> isMapped)
    {
        const int invalid = -1;

        var mappings = new Stack<int>[m];
        var matches = new int[n];

        for (var index = 0; index < n; index++)
        {
            matches[index] = invalid;
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < m; x++)
        {
            var mapping = mappings[x] = new Stack<int>(n);

            for (var y = 0; y < n; y++)
            {
                if (isMapped(x, y))
                {
                    mapping.Push(y);
                }
            }

            var currentX = x;

            while (mapping.TryPop(out var y))
            {
                var tempX = matches[y];
                var otherMapping = tempX != invalid ? mappings[tempX] : null;

                if (otherMapping == null)
                {
                    matches[y] = currentX;
                    break;
                }

                if (otherMapping.Count == 0) continue;

                matches[y] = currentX;
                currentX = tempX;
                mapping = otherMapping;
            }
        }

        for (var index = 0; index < n; index++)
        {
            yield return new BipartiteMatch(matches[index], index);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is my second attempt after @EricLippert's comments.  I created a `State` value to store where the loop stops so it can simulate the pause that would occur during recursion.  There is still a bug somewhere, but I think this may be getting closer.

```
    public struct State
    {
        public int X { get; set; }

        public int Y { get; set; }

        public bool Result { get; set; }
    }

    public static void BipartiteMatch(int x, int n, bool[] seen, int[] matches, Func<int, int, bool> isMapped)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<State>();
        stack.Push(new State {X = x, Y = -1});

        while (stack.TryPop(out var state))
        {
            if (state.Y != -1 && state.Result)
            {
                matches[state.Y] = state.X;
            }
            else
            {
                for (var y = state.Y != -1 ? state.Y : 0; y < n; y++)
                {
                    if (seen[y] || !isMapped(state.X, y)) continue;

                    seen[y] = true;

                    if (matches[y] >= 0)
                    {
                        stack.Push(new State {X = state.X, Y = y});
                        stack.Push(new State {X = matches[y], Y = -1});
                        break;
                    }

                    if (stack.TryPop(out state))
                    {
                        stack.Push(new State {X = state.X, Y = state.Y, Result = true});
                        break;
                    }

                    matches[y] = state.X;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you want to convert a recursive method to iterative method? Does the above give you an error? Oh.. and what have you tried in terms of code to convert the above into iterative approach

Comment: Why do you want to convert?  It probably won't work or you will have a lot of nested for loops.

Comment: Yes, I need to do matching between hundreds of thousands of nodes.  On a small scale, this works perfectly, but scaled up, it causes stack overflow.

Comment: stack overflow only happens when you dont have proper terminations and go in infinite loops over same data. I would suggest fixing the recursive methods and use debugger to see why it goes on and on in an infinite loop rather than converting the method from recursive to many many if / else if / else if statements

Comment: @Jawad: That is not correct; it is entirely possible for a recursion on a small data structure to blow the stack. In Windows, for instance, the stack by default only has a million bytes. If you have a recursively defined data structure with ten thousand nodes in depth and a recursive algorithm that consumes 100 bytes of stack per recursion, that's your million bytes right there.

Comment: "stack overflow only happens when you dont have proper terminations and go in infinite loops over same data," I do not think this is true. There ends up being hundreds of thousands to millions of calls which exceeds the allotted stack depth. As per Wikipedia, "The most-common cause of stack overflow is excessively deep or infinite recursion, in which a function calls itself so many times that the space needed to store the variables and information associated with each call is more than can fit on the stack."

Comment: @Jawad: Now, that said, it is entirely possible that your suggestion here is the correct one; I don't know. My point is merely that we cannot say that stack overflow *only* happens when there is an unbounded recursion.

Comment: @EricLippert I totally understand that and if thats the situation where you are iterating over 100s and 1000s of time over some data causing the size to grow to the point where you run out of resources and get that exception. Converting that sort of recursion would require that many if / else statements which is, in my opinion, not going to work.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam: You say that you do not know how to remove a recursion that is the condition of an `if`.  OK, then the first step should be to remove the recursive step from the condition.  `if (c && recursive(...)) continue;` is the same as `if (c) { bool x = recursive(...); if (x) continue; }` and now the recursive step is *not in the condition of an `if`*.  Can you solve it now?

Comment: @EricLippert I am highly skeptical it is unbound, because there are a finite, countable number of mappings.  That means the number of recursive calls has to be finite and countable as well.  I truly think it is the data sets are so large that it exceeds the stack size.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam  You may want to find out "who" Eric Lippert is...he is the true Jedi Master when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: @Jawad: No, you don't remove the recursion by just adding more `if` statements. There are many other techniques for removing recursions; the original poster attempts the "explicit stack" technique, for example.

Comment: If you want a general method for removing a recursion, I describe how to do so in Python here: https://ericlippert.com/2018/12/03/removing-a-recursion-in-python/  This technique can be used to remove a recursion in C# just as well.

Comment: @EricLippert I will give your suggestions a shot.

Comment: Note that the article shows how to remove a *single* recursion, but you are in the slightly more complex situation of having a recursion in a loop. See if you can work out how to generalize the technique to a recursion in a loop; this is one of those situations where it might be easier to solve the general problem and then apply it to the more specific problem.

Comment: @EricLippert that is what I have been noticing.  It needs to go out of the `for` loop and solve the problem, then return to the `if` statement inside of the loop where it left off.

Comment: @EricLippert I created another attempt based on your suggestions, I think it is closer to the correct solution, but I am still doing something wrong because the results do not match the recursion results.

Comment: Not direct full answer, but, I did this once, and did use a stack to store values, so the stack is ok.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for getting me headed in the right direction.  I believe the solution that I posted is the correct way to represent the original recursive function as an iterative one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured it out, but I would like a second opinion before I say it is all good.

The logic here is each time recursion would be used, push the current state of the loop to the stack along with the state that can answer whether or not the previously stacked state is valid.  If the answer to the question is true, the entire stack is unwound and the method terminates, otherwise, continue searching.

```
    public readonly struct State
    {
        public State(int x, int y = 0)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public int X { get; }

        public int Y { get; }
    }

    public static void BipartiteMatch(int x, int n, bool[] seen, int[] matches, Func<int, int, bool> isMapped)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<State>(new[] {new State(x)});

        while (stack.TryPop(out var state))
        {
            for (var y = state.Y; y < n; y++)
            {
                if (seen[y] || !isMapped(state.X, y)) continue;

                seen[y] = true;

                if (matches[y] >= 0)
                {
                    stack.Push(new State(state.X, y));
                    stack.Push(new State(matches[y]));
                    break;
                }

                matches[y] = state.X;

                while (stack.TryPop(out state))
                {
                    matches[state.Y] = state.X;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```